# field updates and security settings?

Tags: force.com, workflow

I have a field X that by field level security is Read-Only. 
I have a Field update  that's part of my  workflow rule, to update X to a value

Why is that field X getting updated, when FLS has it set to read-only?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Workflows run in [System Mode](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/workflow_field_update_considerations.htm), hence not restricted by FLS.

> Field updates function independently of field-level security.
>   Therefore, a workflow rule can update fields even though they are
>   hidden on the user's page layout.

Workflow field updates however cannot update System Read Only (eg audit fields), Autonumber or Formula fields.